When do you need to normalize the normal vector when applying Stokes' theorem?
I was doing some homework problems on using Stokes' Theorem and I got the correct answer for all but one of the problems. I looked around at other questions related to Stokes' Theorem on here and figured out that I needed to divide by the magnitude of the normal vector, and that indeed brought me to the right answer, but I don't understand why I don't require that step for any of the other problems. I found explanations for why the magnitude of the normal vector cancels out, but I can't figure out why it didn't in this problem. I'll start with the problem I was having trouble with and then include one of the problems I solved correctly for context.

A circle C in the plane x+y+z=1 has a radius of 8 and center (2, -2, 1). Evaluate $\oint_C\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf r$ for $\mathbf F = \langle 0, -4z, -2y\rangle$, where C has counterclockwise orientation when viewed from above.

Here's my attempted solution:
Start by finding the curl of F:
$$ \mathbf F = \langle 0, -4z, -2y\rangle ; \space
\nabla\times\mathbf F =
\begin{vmatrix}
i & j & k \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
0 & -4z & -2y \\
\end{vmatrix}
=\langle2,0,0\rangle \\ $$
Parameterize the plane:
$$ r(x,y)=\langle x,y,1-x-y\rangle \\ $$
Find the partial derivatives of r:
$$ r_x(x,y)=\langle 1,0,-1\rangle \\
r_y(x,y)=\langle 0,1,-1\rangle \\ $$
Find the vector normal to r:
$$ \mathbf n = r_x\times r_y =
\begin{vmatrix}
i & j & k \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{vmatrix} = \langle 1,1,1 \rangle \text{ (vector is pointing in the correct direction)} $$
Calculate the integrand:
$$ (\nabla \times \mathbf F)\cdot \mathbf n = 2(1)+0(1)+0(1) = 2$$
So our integral is:
$$ \iint 2dxdy $$
Convert to polar coordinates so that we can set our bounds of integration as a circle:
$$ \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^8 2rdrd\theta$$
Solve the integral to get:
$$ 128\pi $$
But according to the solution the correct answer is:
$$ \frac{128\pi}{\sqrt{3}} $$

Here's a similar example where I used the same method to get the correct answer:

Confirm that Stokes’ Theorem holds for
the vector field $F=\langle z-y, x, -x\rangle$, where S is the hemisphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$, for $z\ge 0$, and C is the circle $x^2+y^2=4$ oriented counterclockwise.

Start by finding the curl of F:
$$ \mathbf F=\langle z-y,x,-x\rangle ;\space \nabla \times \mathbf F =
\begin{vmatrix}
i & j & k \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
z-y & x & -x \\
\end{vmatrix} = \langle 0,2,2 \rangle $$
Parameterize the surface:
$$ r(x,y)=\langle x, y, \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$$
Find the partial derivatives of r:
$$ r_x(x,y)= \langle 1,0, \frac{-x}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}\rangle \\
r_y(x,y)= \langle 0,1, \frac{-y}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}\rangle$$
Find the vector normal to r:
$$ \mathbf n = r_x\times r_y =
\begin{vmatrix}
i & j & k \\
1 & 0 & \frac{-x}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} \\
0 & 1 & \frac{-y}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} \\
\end{vmatrix} = \langle \frac{x}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}, 1\rangle$$
Calculate the integrand:
$$ (\nabla \times \mathbf F)\cdot \mathbf n = 0(\frac{x}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}) + 2(\frac{y}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}) + 2(1) = \frac{2y}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} + 2$$
So our integral is:
$$ \iint (\frac{2y}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} + 2) dxdy$$
Convert to polar coordinates so that we can set our bounds of integration as a circle:
$$ \int_0^2 \int_0^{2\pi} (\frac{2rsin\theta}{\sqrt{4-r^2}} + 2)rd\theta dr = \int_0^2 \int_0^{2\pi} (\frac{2r^2sin\theta}{\sqrt{4-r^2}} + 2r)d\theta dr $$
In this case, integrating theta first makes the first term drop out and the integral reduces down to:
$$ \int_0^2 4\pi rdr = 8\pi$$
In this case $8\pi$ was the correct answer, so I'm really unsure what I'm missing. I've been trying to figure this out basically all day today. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The mistake in the first example is that when you use $x,y$ as integration variables you are seeing the circle in the plane $x+y+z=1$ as an ellipse. What you integrate in those polar coordinates is a circle as if it were parallel to the $x,y$-plane. Use a smarter approach where you do not have to integrate at all as I showed in the duplicate.

The second example works because the hemisphere seen from the $xy$-plane looks like a disk that is more than fit for integration with polar coordinates.

@KurtG. Thanks you for taking the time to reply. I did see your previous reply on the subject, but I didn't find that answer satisfactory. While I can appreciate the simplicity of the method you explained, I'm in a multivariable calculus class, so it's not as if I can use a method not taught in class to solve the problems. I'm looking for some explanation or intuition of how to solve these integrals, not a different method altogether. I also didn't think that the circle being off-axis was the problem since I had seen other similar problems, but I could be missing something there.

I also tried solving the problem using the single integral F⋅dr as you suggested in that post and I still got the same wrong answer 128π. I could add that solution to the original post, though it's a bit long.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by saying that I'm seeing the circle in the plane as an ellipse. Does normalizing the vector then bring us to a circle?

You parametrized the plane correctly with that $r(x,y),.$ But you did not properly think about the integration limits in $\iint 2,dx,dy,.$ You progressed to polar coordinates as if they were $$\int_{-8}^8\int_{-\sqrt{84-y^2}}^{\sqrt{84-y^2}} 2,dx,dy$$ but that is wrong. I spent quite some time on this an believe that no sane multlivariable calculus teacher can expect students to go that route in this particular case.

Thank you so much for the help. After a long back and forth with my professor he agreed that the question from the Pearson textbook was incorrect.

Why is that? I see nothing wrong with the question and the correct answer to it should be $\frac{128\pi}{\sqrt{3}},.$

Well specifically the provided solution steps seem wrong since it does just set up an integral like I had, but with 2/√3. He also found another example, which I had meant to include in my post instead of the flat circle problem but couldn't find at the time, which is the same off-axis circle problem with slightly different numbers and the solution given is to use Stokes' Theorem just as I did. So he said one of them must be incorrect, and that I shouldn't have to find any unit normal vectors for vector field problems on the exam.
